# Fit control to height of Windows 8 Hub (XAML)

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm using the Hub control in a Windows 8.1 XAML app and I've got a Canvas control that I want to fit to the available height of its HubSection. In HTML I can just set heights to 100%, but I'm stumped on how to do it in XAML. Any clues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general for XAML if you want any UIElement to fill out it's parent horizontally and/or vertically you use the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment properties. By setting these two properties to stretch, the element will fill out it's parent entirely.

However, some controls determines their size based on their content (such as StackPanel). If you have say a empty Grid inside a StackPanel then the resulting size of the StackPanel is (0,0).

It can messy to figure out what is preventing your content from displaying itself as desired. The best way to figure out what is going on is to dig into the templates for the controls you are using.

In your case pertaining to the Hub/HubSection you need to tell the HubSection that the content it hosts should stretch vertically. You can then manually control the width of the element and set it's VerticalAlignment to Stretch.

```
    <Hub>
        <HubSection VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas
                    Background="Red"
                    Width="500">
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
```